HVAC cannot read secret from HashiCorp Vault if /data/ is not used in its path
In HashiCorp Vault I create secrets engine a like this:
vault secrets enable -path=a kv
Success! Enabled the kv secrets engine at: a/

Then I create a secret like this:
vault kv put -mount=a b c=d
Success! Data written to: a/b

It is possible to get the data:
vault kv get -mount=a b
== Data ==
Key    Value
---    -----
c      d

Now I would like to use Python HVAC library:
client = hvac.Client(...) # client is initialized and authenticated
client.secrets.kv.v2.read_secret(path='b', mount_point='a') # this throws exception:
hvac.exceptions.InvalidPath: None, on get http://localhost:8200/v1/a/data/b

I was wondering why localhost:8200/v1/a/data/b is used. According to the documentation it really looks like this path is used /{mount_point}/data/{path}. This is not the path I've created.
I do not know how to use the library without the /data/ subdirectory. Can it be somehow overriden? Do I use the HVAC or Vault secrets incorrectly?
Edit:
This example creates a secret:
client.secrets.kv.v2.create_or_update_secret(path='b', secret=dict(c='d'), mount_point='a')

that can be get like this:
vault kv get -mount=a data/b
===== Data =====
Key        Value
---        -----
data       map[c:d]
options    map[]

So I am not even sure if it's possible to put same data using HVAC and CLI.

It seems it is related with V1 and V2 of KV version.
If I use V1 I am able to get data created on command line.
client.secrets.kv.v1.read_secret('b', 'a')['data']
{'c': 'd'}

